# C - How to find a winner of a norts and crosses

Tags: c, arrays

I am currently making a tic tac toe game using C. I am making a function Check(char sign) that i can call after each player makes a move which will check for a winner. I need help as the tic tac toe game can be played on different sized boards (3 up to 12).

I made the following code which can be used to find the winner of a 3 x 3 game:

```
**//For Rows**
for(i=0; i<3; i++)/***sign is the player symbol e.g. 'X'OR'O'***/
    if(board[i][0] == sign && board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == ` 
     board[i][2]){`
         printf("the winner is %c", sign );
         return 1;
}

**//For Columns** 
for(i=0; i<3; i++)/***sign is the player symbol e.g. 'X'OR'O'***/
    if(board[0][i] == sign && board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == 
        board[2][i]){
        printf("the winner is %c", sign );
        return 1;
}

**//For Diagnal 1 \**
if(board[0][0] == sign && board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == 
    board[2][2]){
    printf("the winner is %c", sign );
    return 1;
}

**//For Diagnal 2 /**
if(board[0][2] == sign && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == 
    board[2][0]){
    printf("the winner is %c", sign );
    return 1;
}
```

However as I mentioned my game can be played on different board sizes which is chosen by user input at the beginining of the game. This size is stored in a vreriable "int Size". How would I alter the above code to work with any size board?

I know that i could create a list if statements each one containing code for a specific board size but this seems like the incorrect and least efficient way of doing so.

I hope someone can help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just watch the movie Wargames, in particular the end.

Comment: How are you representing the board, now that the size isn't known prior to execution?

Comment: the braces for the if statements in the loops do not align.

Comment: Is your board always defined as `nxn`?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `if` statement for each of your 4 cases could be written using a loop; for example, the first one could be written as:

```
int win = (board[i][0] == sign); // assume a win until we find out otherwise
// loop over the pairs to compare until we find a mismatch or exhaust them all
for ( int j = 1; (win == 1) && (j < size); j++ )
    if ( board[i][j-1] != board[i][j] )
        win = 0;
if ( win ) {
     printf("the winner is %c", board[i][0] );
     return 1;
}
```

Change which 2 elements of `board` are being compared, and the initialization of `win`, for each of the other 3 cases.

Comment: This is assumed to be inside the loop you already have; it is replacing the `if` statement specific to a 3x3 board.

Answer (score 1):

You could have three function, one that iterates through rows, one that iterates through cols, and one that iterates through the diagonal pair.

```
/* If the sign player won, return 1. Else return 0. */
int rowWinnerCheck(int n, char sign, char board[n][n]){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int sameSign = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            char letter = board[i][j];
            if(letter != sign){
                sameSign = 0;
            }
        }
        if(sameSign == 1){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`colWinnerCheck` would be similar to how `rowWinnerCheck` is implemented.

Verifying if a player won diagonally is also similar.

```
/* This function checks if a player won diagonally from the top-left to bottom-right*/
int diagonalWinnerCheck(int n, char sign, char board[n][n]){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int sameSign = 1;
        char letter = board[i][i];
        if(letter != sign){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

---

**Solution without loops**

Here is a possible solution without loops, which I believe scales better for a larger `n`.

I'll leave the C out for you to complete, and I'll just explain the concept for determining the winner on an `n x n` board. The code you gave uses loops to compare the contents on the board. This solution doesn't depend on loops as it makes use of a mathematical representation to determine the winner.

**Board Representation**

We first need to have a representation for the board using a 2D array of integer of size `n x n`. We will also make everything zero in the board from the start.

```
int board[n][n];
memset(board, 0, sizeof(board[0][0]) * n * n);
```

We define the letters that are used, `X` and `O`, and assign them to be the constants, `1` and `-1` respectively. *Note: 1, -1 were choose arbitrarily, but for the solution to work, they need to be some integer k, -k*.

We define four more items for the solution. Two integer arrays, one to represent the rows and one for the cols, and two integers for the two diagonals.

```
int rows[n] = {0};
int cols[n] = {0};
int leftDiag = 0;
int rightDiag = 0;
```

**How it Works**

Let's assume a new game was started on a 3x3 board. I play X, and you play O. I make my move on location (2,0). The program first checks the board location at (2,0) and sees if it's zero. If it is, set it to be `X`, else raise an error since that spot has been played already. The program also adds `X` to `rows[2]` and `cols[0]`.

You play O at (1,1). First check if `board[1][1]` has been already played, if not, set it to be `O`. Add `O` to `rows[1]` and `cols[1]`. Here is a special case. When you player played O on the diagonal i.e. for a move `(a,b)` `a == b` or `a == (n-b-1)`, add `O` to the appropriate diagonal variable. Since (1,1) belongs to both diagonal, add `O` to `leftDiag` and `rightDiag`.

We alternate turns until one of these conditions are met:

- A location `i` in `rows` such that `rows[i] == n * X`. This means X
  won by     filling    the ith row. A location `j` in rows such that
  `rows[j] == n * O`. This means O won
- A location `i` in `cols` such that `cols[i] == n * X`. This means X
  won by     filling    the ith col. A location `j` in cols such that
  `cols[j] == n * O`. This means O won
- `leftDiag == n * X` or `rightDiag == n * X`, X won. `leftDiag == n * O` or `rightDiag == n * O`, O won.
- `n*n` moves have been made, but the previous conditions were
  never met. This mean the game ended in a tie.

Notice that at the end, we don't need to iterate through rows, cols, or diagonals to verify if someone won. If a row, col, or diagonal, sums up throughout the game to be `n * Character`, then that Character player won. This reduces the complexity of verifying a winner from `O(n^2)` to `O(1)`. The trade off is just `O(n)` more space.